# Communicating between the main and renderer function in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is there a way to communicate between the main and renderer process in Puppeteer similar to the [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) and [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) functions in [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

A simple application is demonstrated in this [post](http://electron.rocks/different-ways-to-communicate-between-main-and-renderer-process/). I find this functionality can be useful for debugging by triggering event from the `page` to the main function and vice-versa.

Comment: Do you mean node context and browser context?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for triggering events from the node context to the browser and vice versa. In Electron, there is the "ipc" module that helps do this

Comment: Please be more specific, how do you want to use this? Any code snippet?

Comment: Please check the link I referenced in my question. This [post](http://electron.rocks/different-ways-to-communicate-between-main-and-renderer-process/) explains the kind of interaction I need. I want to trigger a few clicks at the client side based on inputs from the node context. I want to pass data to a function in the node context after obtaining the data from the browser context

Comment: :) I used nightmare, electron, ipcRenderer and all things mentioned. I am talking about more details and example codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puppeteer log inside page.evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198527/puppeteer-log-inside-page-evaluate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debugging:
- Puppeteer has various page events used for debugging purpose [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page). 
- Puppeteer recently [added ASYNC stack trace](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/3262) so you can track errors more precisely.

Event emitting,
You can use the default `events` module and `exposeFunction` to build your own events system.

Refer to the following code snippet that has all of the mentioned methods,

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const myEventTracker = new EventEmitter();
myEventTracker.on("some-event", function(...data) {
  // do something on event
  console.log(data);
});

// usage in puppeteer
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // normal console events forwarded to node context
  page.on("console", msg => console.log(msg.text()));

  // we can use this to make our own reverse events
  myEventTracker.on("change-viewport", async function(data) {
    // do something on event
    await page.setViewport({ width: data.width, height: data.height });
  });

  // or we can expose the emit function
  await page.exposeFunction("emitter", (...data) =>
  myEventTracker.emit(...data)
  );

  // emit however we want
  await page.evaluate(async => {
    emitter("change-viewport", { width: 1200, height: 800 });
    emitter("some-event", "inside browser");
  });

  await page.goto("http://viewportsizes.com/mine/");
  // await browser.close();
});
```

It will become a blog post if we want to explain all, I will update my answer otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Sir! This has everything I need to get started.