# Can't scrape and print the links on the fly

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, promise, puppeteer

I've written a script in `node.js` to scrape the `links` of different titles from a webpage. When I execute my following script, I get `undefined` printed in the console instead of the `links` I'm after. My defined selectors are accurate.

I do not wish to put the `links` in an array and return the results; rather, I wish to print them on the fly. As I'm very new to write scripts using `node.js` in combination with `puppeteer`, I can't figure out the mistake I'm making.

This is my script ([Link to that site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping)):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping");
            let url = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.question-hyperlink');
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    //would like to keep the following line intact 
                    console.log(item.getAttribute('href'));
                });
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(url);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

> The following script works just fine if I consider to declare an empty array `results` and store the scraped links within it and finally return the `results`but I do not wish to go like this. I would like to stick to the way I tried above, as in printing the result on the fly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping");
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let results = [];
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.question-hyperlink');
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    results.push({
                        url:  item.getAttribute('href'),
                    });
                });
                return results;
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

***Once again: my question is how can I print the link like `console.log(item.getAttribute('href'));` on the fly without storing it in an array?***

Comment: Which console log call gives `undefined` prints? for example, `url` variable will always be undefined because you are not returning anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between the main and renderer function in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684640/communicating-between-the-main-and-renderer-function-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `console.log()` inside `evaluate()` simply copy the line below where you are defining page

```
page.on('console', obj => console.log(obj._text));
```

so now the whole snippet will be like this now

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            page.on('console', obj => console.log(obj._text));
            await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping");
            let url = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.question-hyperlink');
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    //would like to keep the following line intact 
                    console.log(item.getAttribute('href'));
                });
            })
            browser.close();
            return resolve(url);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Atishay Jain. My second script is already working. I do not wish to comply that logic; rather, I want to print the result on the fly like I tried in my first script.

Comment: sorry got the question wrong the first time i've updated the answer. please check @asmitu

Comment: Now this is more like it. Thanks @Atishay Jain for your working solution. Let's wait few more days while the bounty is on.

Answer (score 1):

The library looks a bit awkward to use but found the proper way to get an href from this thread on github- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/628

The working code I have is to use `await page.$$eval`

```
async function getStackoverflowLinks(){
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject)=>{
    console.log(`going to launch chromium via puppeteer`)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    console.log(`creating page/tab`)
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping')
    console.log("fetched SO web-scraping, now parsing link href")

    let matches = await page.$$eval('a.question-hyperlink', hrefs=>hrefs.map((a)=>{
      return a.href
    })) // $$eval and map version, $$eval returns an array
    console.log("matches = ", matches.length)

    await browser.close()
    resolve(matches)
  })
}

getStackoverflowLinks()
.then(hrefs=>{
  console.log("hrefs: ", hrefs)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to note,

- `async` function will return a promise.
- `new Promise` will also return a promise.

On that note, you can simply use the `.console` events to print them on fly. Usage,

```
page.on("console", msg => console.log(msg.text()));
await page.evaluate(async => {
  console.log("I will be printed on node console too")
})
```

Advanced usage has been discussed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52706462/6161265).